# How to mask string?

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting, masking

I have a string with value "1131200001103".

How can I display it as a string in this format "11-312-001103" using Response.Write(value)?

Thanks

Comment: Possible Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509172/apply-mask-to-a-string

Comment: and you are looking to accomplish what? because that thing can be done using substrings and concatenate

Comment: Please read more carefully, this is not a dup.

Comment: @gbianchi that would be my alternative. I am looking for a better solution/approach

Comment: So, to make your question better, explain why substring is not a solution, or why you think there should be a better solution. substring is too slow? too much code? too hard on some cases?? string can be variable lenght?  Look at Jon answer...

Comment: Are you looking for a C# version of C++'s `scanf` function?

Comment: @John: No, I was just trying to understand your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This produces the required result

```
string result = Int64.Parse(s.Remove(5,2)).ToString("00-000-000000");
```

assuming that you want to drop 2 characters at the position of the 2 first nulls.

Comment: Works really nice with masking numbers to strings.

Answer (score 16):

Any reason you don't want to just use [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)?

```
string dashed = text.Substring(0, 2) + "-" +
                text.Substring(2, 3) + "-" +
                text.Substring(7);
```

Or:

```
string dashed = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", text.Substring(0, 2),
                              text.Substring(2, 3), text.Substring(7));
```

(I'm assuming it's deliberate that you've missed out two of the 0s? It's not clear *which* 0s, admittedly...)

Obviously you should validate that the string is the right length first...

Comment: And OP looks for a better solution according to his comment.. is there a better solution??

Comment: I appreciate Jon's answer, that is almost identical to my solution. Oliver's solution is also a good one. I just wanted to see is there a masking solution similar to text-box masking.

Comment: @Jon Two 0s are deliberate. I am actually masking third party response codes, but I guess 8 digits were too much for their documentation as well. They are using 1131200001103 as a raw response and 11-312-001103 in their documentation.

Comment: @John: Do you know which of the 0s should be removed though? For example, if the original was 11111145671111 would the result be 11-111-451111 or 11-111-671111 - or something different?

Comment: First two 0s of the third part. So the result would be 11-111-671111. ##-###-######. You have extra chars in your original string.

Answer (score 12):

You can try a regular expression and put this inside an extension method ToMaskedString()

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToMaskedString(this String value)
    {
        var pattern = "^(/d{2})(/d{3})(/d*)$";
        var regExp = new Regex(pattern);
        return regExp.Replace(value, "$1-$2-$3");
    }
}
```

Then call

```
respne.Write(value.ToMaskedString());
```

Comment: ToMaskedString return an int?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "^(/d{2})(/d{3})(/d{2})(/d*)$" and "$1-$2-$4" in order to drop the two 0s?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a quick extension method for same / similar purpose (similar in a sense that there's no way to skip characters).

Usage:

```
var testString = "12345";
var maskedString = testString.Mask("##.## #"); // 12.34 5
```

Method:

```
public static string Mask(this string value, string mask, char substituteChar = '#')
{
    int valueIndex = 0;
    try
    {
        return new string(mask.Select(maskChar => maskChar == substituteChar ? value[valueIndex++] : maskChar).ToArray());
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Value too short to substitute all substitute characters in the mask", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great general mask solution!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like

```
string result = str.SubString(0, 2) + "-" + str.SubString(2, 3) + "-" + str.SubString(7);
```

str being the "11312000011103" string

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) approach you can take:

```cs
Response.Write($"{value[..2]}-{value[2..5]}-{value[^6..]}");
```

Comment: Best modern approach to do this

Answer (score 0):

I've complemented the Answer from @ESipalis

The extension method accepts a Array of chars to be replaced

```
public static string Mask(this string value, string mask, char[] substituteChar)
  {
     int valueIndex = 0;
     try
     {
        return new string(mask.Select(maskChar => substituteChar.Contains(maskChar) ? value[valueIndex++] : maskChar).ToArray());
     }
     catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
     {
        return "#ERROR";
     }
  }
```

And you can call the extension:

```
yourString.Mask("AAA-999(SSS)","AS9".ToArray())
```