# How can I convert byte array data to a format that looks like a product key

Tags: c#, byte, licensing

I am creating a license software key and currently I get a byte array after encryption process. How do I convert this byte array (may be of size 2000) to a product key that looks like xxxxx - xxxxx - xxxxx - xxxxx - xxxxx where x can be a value that ranges from upper case A-Z and 0-9?

I am trying this out to generate a license key in c# console app and to validate the generated license.

```
var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
//memoryStream is a cryptostream and the size of the byte array can be around 2000
```

I expect the byte array to be converted into a nicely formatted key that looks like the format I mentioned above. I have been stuck with this for past 2 weeks. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mask string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705955/how-to-mask-string)

Comment: @collenbrecht, that is one workaround I am possibly thinking of to use but it requires additional steps while validating a key.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])`. This will give you a string with A-Z, a-z, 0-9. Then you can manually add `-` using `string.Substring` method.

Comment: I tried this but it contains other characters other that what I need. Also, the resulting string is more than the expected length of 34.

Comment: @Jabez, you can encode 1 char (A-Z,0-9) with 1 byte. So you can not wrap 2000 bytes into 25-char string. If you want a short string you can get a hash function from your byte array

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Guid`.

```
Guid.NewGuid();
```

[Documentation about Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Guid works good, but there are other crypto techniques used in my code that resulted in a byte array of size more than 2000 and hence the problem to convert that into a string of length 34 as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Create an Hash with sha256