# Data annotations - DisplayFormat - formatting string of numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have the following string: `"10222002750400447092095835"`

I want it to be displayed like this: `10 2220 0275 0400 4470 9209 5835`

I tried doing the following, with no result at all:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

or

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:## #### #### #### #### #### ####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please show where you use the property, and how ?

Comment: For the case of simplicity, here: `String.Format("{0:## #### #### #### #### #### ####}", "10222002750400447092095835");`. The problem is exactly in the argument - its a string, and string is not IFormattable. But how can i omit that? This argument needs to be a string.

Comment: There you said it - you'd need to implement `IFormattable` yourself in order to use custom formats. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10512433/63733

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is String masking. See below.

[Stackoverflow - How to mask a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705955/how-to-mask-string)
[Stackoverflow - Apply mask to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509172/apply-mask-to-a-string)

Comment: Well thanks. I couldn't exactly use a mask, but i created a custom attribute that does similar things. :)